# Уникальное поле с пустым значением

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Есть модель у которой поле уникальное и может быть null. Но проблема в том что эти два понятия как бы друг-другу противоречат: если я пытаюсь сделать два поля null то мне выдает ошибку, т.к. уже есть поле со значением null. Как быть? Например:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    identifier = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

P.S. Т.е. мне бы хотелось чтобы уникальность не распространялась на случай когда установлено значение null.

Python 2.7, Django 1.8

Что еще интересно: когда я добавляю первую пустую запись у меня в БД отображается не пустая строка, а какие-то два апострофа ''. Совершенно не понятно откуда они там берутся. В коде ничего такого нет. И при этом в админке у этой модели не отображается это поле и соответственно нельзя даже перейти на эту модель. Зато если я добавляю в БД руками пустую строку в это поле, то у меня в админке выводится надпись "(Ничего)" и туда можно перейти.

Нашел один вроде бы рабочий вариант [тут](http://bitofpixels.com/blog/unique-on-charfield-when-blanktrue/). Но возникла другая проблема - теперь в админке на месте этого поля (у тех строк где оно пустое) вообще ничего нет. Как задать текст отображаемый при пустом пустом значении? Как по умолчанию отображалось "(Ничего)".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста свою версию django

Comment: Добавил в пост.

Comment: У меня обе записи добавились нормально с default=None. Django 1.9.4

Comment: Ну не знаю, может там что-то изменилось в этом плане по сравнению с 1.8. Обновиться не имею возможности. Кстати погуглив эту проблему как следует я понял что она вообще-то не только у меня... Как пример та ссылка которую я дал выше или вот еще [например](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015063/nullable-textfield-or-empty-string-in-django-model) (кстати приведен тот же код один в один).

Comment: Отображение в админке - вручную нужно настроить, есть несколько методов на вкус. Кстати, в django 1.9 есть ещё и специальный метод для пустого значения: [empty_value_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.empty_value_display)